# Create/Increment ObservableCollection On Button Click

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, increment

I am looking to see if it is possible to be able to increment an `ObservableCollection`every time a button is clicked?

```
ObservableCollection<string> _title = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public ObservableCollection<string> Title
{
    get { return _title; }
    set
    {
        _title = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(() => Title);
    }
}
```

As shown from the C# code above, I have an `ObservableCollection` for a Title. Currently, when I add a new title, every title goes into the same collection. However, what I am aiming to achieve is; every time the "Add Title" button is pressed, a **new** title is added and a **new** `ObservableCollection` is created. Is this possible, and how can it be done?

**EDIT1**

At the moment I dynamically create `Textboxes` and then add whatever string I want to that `Textbox`. From there I save the `Stackpanel`, named 'Content', into a `.txt` file. In this file it will hold the `Textboxs` that have been created. (*It does not save the string into that file due to the textbox being binded*). I then thought the strings would be saved into a list, and when I load the `Stackpanel` back up from the `.txt` file the string would get added back to the `Textbox`.

**EDIT2**

I have changed a bit of code:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    this.AddTitleCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>((o) => OnAddTitle()));
}

private void OnAddTitle()
{

    NewTitle += titleName;
}
```

When doing this it is not adding my string as a word it is separating the letters in my string in separate titles.

Comment: A new title(string) is need to add to that collection right?

Comment: why you wanna do this? what about the "old" titles within the "old" collection?

Comment: Please explain *every time the "Add Title" button is pressed, a new title is added and a new ObservableCollection is created* further and clearer. Do you want one collection, or multiple collections?

Comment: @Sankarann Possibly, if that can be done.

Comment: @blindmeis Because each title needs its own collection, as I'm going to add stuff under each title. If I used the old collection, then all the titles go into one collection, which is not what I want.

Comment: @Sheridan Multiple collections for multiple titles. One collection per title.

Comment: I think you need `Dictionary` kind of Collection. Am i right? Do you aware of `Dictionary Collection`?

Comment: A `StackPanel` is not the same thing as an `ItemsControl`. You should bind any enumeration to an `ItemsControl`, and if you want the items to show up stacked, then override the the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` to set it as a `StackPanel`. http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/02/10/itemscontrol-p-is-for-panel/

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, each time your `Button` is pressed, you want to add a new `string` into a new collection. You then said that you will add other values into each collection... this sounds like you're trying to fulfil your requirements in the wrong way, but you didn't tell us what those were, so we can't help you with that. Here's how you can add a new collection each time:

```
private string newTitle = string.Empty;
private ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> collections = new 
    ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>();

public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> Collections
{
    get { return collections; }
    set { collections = value; OnPropertyChanged(() => Collections); }
}

public string NewTitle
{
    get { return newTitle; }
    set { newTitle = value; OnPropertyChanged(() => NewTitle); }
}

public void AddCollection()
{
    ObservableCollection<string> collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    collection.Add(NewTitle);
    Collections.Add(collection);
}
```

The `NewTitle` property could be data bound to a `TextBox` in the UI allowing users to enter the new values and when the `Button` is pressed, the `AddCollection` method would add it into a new collection and then add that into the `Collections` collection.

I still think that this is *not* a good idea though.

---

UPDATE >>>

Please stop what you're doing... programs are not written like that. We save data, the `string`s, *not* UI elements. There is absolutely no point in saving the UI elements along with all their extra property values that you have no interest in. Whatever method you have of displaying the `string`s in the `TextBox`es can be reused each time the *data* is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This code is fine, but I have an error that has occurred in this line `this.Collections.Add(titleName);` this is when I am passing what is in the title box to the collection aswell, `string titleName;`

Comment: Look at my code again... I'm *not* adding a `string` into a collection of `string` collections. I'm adding a `string` into a collection of `string`s and *then* adding that collection of `string`s into the collection of `string` collections.

Comment: I understand now. However, apologies for not making it clearer in my question, but the title is not only a string, it is also linked to XAML and passes a text box too. Therefore, that is why I made the Title an ObservableCollection instead of a string.

Comment: It's still no clearer... but I hope you're not saying that you're trying to add UI elements into your collections, because we *don't* do that in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

ObservableCollection provides a constructor that takes an IEnumerable so use it to create a new instance with the same titles and add your new title afterward :

```
ObservableCollection<string> newCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(Title);
newCollection.Add(theNewTitle)
Title = newCollection;
```